# Cut out image in shape of text

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I need to cut out an image in the shape of the text in another image. I think it's best shown in images.

This is a photo of a cat:

[image: Photo of a nice cat]

and this is the text I wish to cut out:

[image: Text to cut out of the cat photo]

The resulting image would be this:

[image: Resulting cut-out of the cat photo]

The text image will always be black with a transparent background, and the resulting cut-out should too have a transparent background. Both input images will also be the same size.

Comment: Whatever. Cat? Immediate +1!

Comment: You filled up the internal "a" hole. Was that intentional?

Comment: @belisarius Well spotted - no that was not intentional ;)

Comment: Wouldn't be better if you have an image and a text instead? ( just asking )

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create a new BufferedImage and iterate over all the pixels of word cat and if they are black, copy the cat-image pixels to the new image.

Here is some code: (**Final working code, supports anti-alias**)

```
public static BufferedImage textEffect(BufferedImage image, BufferedImage text) {
    if (image.getWidth() != text.getWidth() ||
        image.getHeight() != text.getHeight())
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dimensions are not the same!");
    }
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(),
                                          image.getHeight(),
                                          BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);

    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); ++x) {
           int textPixel = text.getRGB(x, y);
           int textAlpha = (textPixel & 0xFF000000);
           int sourceRGB = image.getRGB(x, y);
           int newAlpha = (int) (((textAlpha >> 24) * (sourceRGB >> 24)) / 255d);
           int imgPixel = (newAlpha << 24) |  (sourceRGB & 0x00FFFFFF);
           int rgb = imgPixel | textAlpha;
           img.setRGB(x, y, rgb);

        }
    }
    return img;
}
```

Comment: How would you iterate over all pixels of word cat? What if the word is dog? From OP - the text is always in black, so just replace all black pixels with corresponsing pixels from other image?

Comment: @Lobo Yes, that is what he is suggesting.

Comment: One tiny suggestion: instead of converting to `double` when calculating `newAlpha`, just move the division to the end after the multiplication.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks, it is indeed a bit neater.

Answer (score 39):

[image: Cat text]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.File;

class PictureText {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqf3H.jpg");
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(url);
        final BufferedImage textImage = new BufferedImage(
            originalImage.getWidth(),
            originalImage.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = textImage.createGraphics();
        FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontRenderContext();
        Font font = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 250);
        GlyphVector gv = font.createGlyphVector(frc, "Cat");
        Rectangle2D box = gv.getVisualBounds();
        int xOff = 25+(int)-box.getX();
        int yOff = 80+(int)-box.getY();
        Shape shape = gv.getOutline(xOff,yOff);
        g.setClip(shape);
        g.drawImage(originalImage,0,0,null);
        g.setClip(null);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.draw(shape);

        g.dispose();

        File file = new File("cat-text.png");
        ImageIO.write(textImage,"png",file);
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: JDK only solution

Answer (score 15):

Use `GlyphVector`. Use `Font` class

```
public GlyphVector layoutGlyphVector(FontRenderContext frc,
                                         char[] text,
                                         int start,
                                         int limit,
                                         int flags) {
```

You can get outline `Shape` from glyph vector by public abstract Shape `getOutline()`

Assign the outline `Shape` as a clip to your `Graphics` instance.

Draw the image on the graphics.

Only clipped shape will be filled.

Answer (score 8):

No java here, but the needed image operations are easy to understand. In Mathematica:

[image]

Comment: probably the OP wants to create a method like this in first place.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in Java with just a few lines of source code, using [Marvin Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/)

[image]

**source code:**

```
public class CutAndFill {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 1. Load images
        MarvinImage catImage = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/catImage.jpg");
        MarvinImage catText = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/catText.png");

        // 2. Load plug-in, set parameters and process de image
        MarvinImagePlugin combine = MarvinPluginLoader.loadImagePlugin("org.marvinproject.image.combine.combineByMask");
        combine.setAttribute("combinationImage", catImage);
        combine.setAttribute("colorMask", Color.black);
        combine.process(catText.clone(), catText);

        // 3. Save the output image.
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(catText, "./res/catOut.jpg");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First, make the black portion of the "Cat" image transparent.  See [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0265.html) for help with this.  Then, [composite](http://www.javareference.com/jrexamples/viewexample.jsp?id=105) that image over the picture of your favorite cat (mine is Sheeba).

The nice thing about this is you can make the transparent text image once, save it, and then apply it to all of Sheeba's family and friends!