# How I can set pixel in the Shape with the specific RGB?

Tags: java, set, rgb, shapes

For example, I have a polygon and I need to fill it with the specific RGB. How can I do it? I tried to convert shape to image, but then I can't set a pixel with setRGB method from BufferedImage(pixel color wasn't changing!):

```
...
    Rectangle2D r = pgnProjection.getBounds();
    BufferedImage rectBuffIm = new BufferedImage(r.getBounds().width, r.getBounds().height, 
                                        BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
    for(int i = rectBuffIm.getWidth()/2, j = rectBuffIm.getHeight()/2; rectBuffIm.getWidth()>i && rectBuffIm.getHeight()>j; j++, i++)
        rectBuffIm.setRGB(i, j, rgb);

    Graphics2D gr2D = rectBuffIm.createGraphics();
    gr2D.translate(-pgnProjection.getBounds().x, -pgnProjection.getBounds().y);
    gr2D.draw(pgnProjection);
    gr2D.dispose();
...
```

Also, image background was black, and set pixels were always white.

Answer (score 1):

Call `Graphics.setClip(Shape)` followed by the drawing operations.  See here for [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295084/cut-out-image-in-shape-of-text/6296381#6296381).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Graphics.fillPolygon()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillPolygon%28java.awt.Polygon%29)

Comment: I must fill pixels of different colors not one color.