# How to create complex GUI like this in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm a beginner in `java` and so far I've found resources just about how to build simple GUIs using predefined components like text fields and buttons (i.e. `Swing`). 
How about build from your own layout without any restrictions? 
Like the example below:

[image: Example Player]

Comment: What I would do is start with [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html).  I would then create an image of the UI you want to make and generate some kind of image map, which described the areas of the map which were "active", allowing your to perform simpler checks of the mouse position

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205164/java-custom-shaped-frame-using-image/26208568#26208568), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906687/how-can-i-smooth-my-jframe-shape/13906713#13906713), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588786/jframe-the-same-shape-as-an-image-program-running-in-background/13594794#13594794)

Comment: May I ask why you would want to create such a non-standard GUI in the first place? It looks like too much [skeuomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph) to me.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The example is there just to illustrate a complex gui, it's not this one I'll try. I'm looking for something more close to HTML/CSS. Despite the fact that the is FXML I didn't find it as good as HTML/CSS.

Comment: @Telephone Sorry to say, but I think you're going to be bitterly disappointed then

Comment: If anyone has a JavaFX example, please post it in the comments, I'd be interested in seeing it as well