# How to create a custom shape for the frame object in a java application

Tags: java

I want to create a custom shape for my frame. I have found a method called setShape that takes a shape object. But i am not able to implement the shape interface properly. I have looked up all the related posts on the internet but none of them helped me. Please provide a working example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163544/re-paint-problem-on-translucent-frame-panel-component/2166500#2166500

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205164/java-custom-shaped-frame-using-image

Comment: they may help you. please read that.

Comment: you cannot create a custom shape frame

Comment: Making a transparent Frame is not the same as making it a custom shape. It will still receive / block events

Comment: Its possible i have created it using generalPath object. It does not make the frame transparent or anything.