# How to define a complex shape?

Tags: java, image, shapes

For this image, I am trying to define a shape for each "territory".  How would I accomplish doing this?

[image: Image that is to be divided into shapes]

Comment: This seems like a good starting point: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/complexshapes.html - are you trying to draw it, or do hit detection, or something else?

Comment: What have you tried? What ideas do you have, that we might be able to improve upon?

Comment: @Chris: I'm trying to have something happen when the user clicks inside a territory. I don't know if there is a better way to do it :P

Comment: @WATTO Studios: I don't have any ideas on how to do this, as the regions can't easily be defined as a combination of simple shapes. As a last resort, I might have a button in the middle that the user can click on, but that doesn't seem very creative to me.

Comment: The code on [Smoothing a jagged path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218309/smoothing-a-jagged-path) will provide an edge between two colors, but it is not 'per pixel' smooth (see thread for details).  Given your image is so large, it might not be a problem.  But also, if you can devote the time to figuring how to take out those 'bumpy bits', add it as an answer to my original question to get a 'tick'.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you want to implement, but this generic approach should work:

- Discretely separate the regions in your image using boundary lines, so they no longer tough each other.  (Using morphological erodes, for example.)
- Do a "connected component" (CC) operation on the images to generate a different label for each region's pixels (1, 2, 3, ...).  You can probably find some code online to do this, but it's easy to write your own CC function.
- When a user clicks on a region, map the mouse's X/Y coordinate onto your labeled image to find the region label under that point, and report the label.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you can define the shapes of your territories as a series of points - ie (x1, y1), (x2, y2), etc, then you can use one of the hit testing algorithms defined here: [How can I determine whether a 2D Point is within a Polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test) (several great answers there, general enough that you could adapt the concepts to fit your needs).