# Can you draw Area objects with Graphics g?

Tags: java, awt, collision-detection, draw, area

I am trying to implement a collision detection system between different objects. I got the idea of using Area for the purpose of collision detection from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574045/collision-detection-with-complex-shapes).

This isn't quite working on my program like it did in the answer and I am getting collisions between two objects before they should collide and they stop before they should stop.

I am not sure which Area is off, either the left object's area is over to the right, or the right object's area is over to the left, or a mix of both.

I'm having trouble finding a way to get the areas on the screen visually so I can see where they are. Graphics does not support a `drawArea();` or anything.

I created the Areas from existing Geom objects:

```
private Ellipse2D collisionCircle = new Ellipse2D.Double(0,0,0,0);
private Area collisionArea;

// later inside the update() method
collisionCircle.setFrame(posX - 61, posY - 61, 122, 122);
collisionArea = new Area(collisionCircle);
```

I use the same technique for the other object:

```
private Rectangle collisionRect = new Rectangle(0,0,0,0);
private Area collisionArea;

// later in the update() method
collisionRect.setRect(posX - 61, posY - 61, 122, 122);
collisionArea = new Area(collisionRect);
```

In the main game section I've used the same collision method from the previously mentioned question.

**The result**

The objects that the area is made from (the rectangle and the ellipse) are both drawn to the screen with a 1 pixel border and can clearly be seen. They begin colliding (according to this method) way before they should, and stop while they should still be colliding.

I want to be able to visually represent the Area objects, not the geometirc objects so I can trouble shoot this. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Area` implements `Shape`.  `Graphics2D` can draw and fill `Shape`s, so yes, you can draw an `Area`

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927189/detecting-collision-of-two-sprites-that-can-rotate/20928531#20928531)