# How can java detect collision of shapes that are stored in an array Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collision-detection, collision, shapes

So what am trying to do is to enable the user to draw rectangles and detect collisions between rectangles.

The rectangles are added into an Array_List shapes:

```
ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
```

and for the collisions java must go through the ArrayList to detect collisions of shapes. (Any other ways to detect the collision is fine).
I know that java has a ".intersects()" method for shapes but here it's more about many shapes and i don't know how to use it here.

Here is a small beginning of what i've done so far for the collisions, am ready stuck on that. Please do help?

```
if (currentAction == 4) {

// Create a new rectangle using x & y coordinates 

aShape = drawRectangle(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
 e.getX(), e.getY());

//aShape added to the arraylist shapes
 shapes.add(aShape);                                                             

 for(int i=0;i<shapes.size();i++){                            
Shape s = shapes.get(i);

  //collision detection                                 

 }
  }
```

Comment: There are multiple ways you might determine if two shapes collide, depending on you needs.  Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927189/detecting-collision-of-two-sprites-that-can-rotate/20928531#20928531) for one.

Comment: @MadProgrammer In your example, two rectangles are already defined.. what is need is to detect for collisions between the rectangles that i will draw.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just want the program to go through the array, read the coordinates of the shapes, compare them and find what shape collides. Can you please help?

Comment: The basic principles of comparing two `Shape`s doesn't change.  You just need to determine how you can loop through a `List` of them and compare them.  Hint, you may need a compound loop...

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer i've been able to do it!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll will tip you - try to read on dynamic programing and try to break the collisions to one who happen horizontally and one who happen vertically.

I hope it helps...

Comment: I can't really understand what you mean by breaking the collisions to one. What am trying to do is to find any collisions between the shapes that are stored inside the arraylist.

Comment: What I mean is that you first need to sort and then iterate the ArrayList and look for collisions in the X-axis, if you didn't find such a collision you can iterate again and check for Y-axis collision. Another solution would be to use intersect() method with each of the shapes in O(n^2) complexity.

Comment: i did thought of the intersect() method  but how to compare when the shapes are inside the array list ?

Comment: For each shape in the list, compare it with the other shapes in the list. But it is really insufficient.

Comment: what can you suggest?