# How do I test overlap (or collision) of two arbitrary shapes

Tags: java, android, geometry, collision-detection, polygon

I'm looking for a Java library which I can use to compute the collision of two simple (no intersecting lines or holes) 2D polygons.

The specific implementation is a drag-and-drop "sticker" applicator where the user drags various solid shapes around the screen and the shapes may not overlap.

I have a vague idea of how to write this myself but am hoping to avoid reinventing this bicycle, however, after a number of searches I'm unable to find anything useful.

Comment: This is completely off topic, but this here: http://www.jbox2d.org/ I have never used it myself.

Comment: @WalterM, how is that "off topic"? Looks like exactly what I'm looking for! I'll give it a whirl and see if it has what I need. You should propose this as an answer, I'll upvote it! :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, that looks like a collision test for rectangles - I need it to work on arbitrary shapes - am I overlooking its capacity to deal with this use case?

Comment: You could also have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927189/detecting-collision-of-two-sprites-that-can-rotate/20928531#20928531)

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: If you make use of the Shape API, then the previous and new link will still work, I just used rectangles cause they were simple to implement ;). I'm not sure how much of the API is available in android though. The newer example goes into more details about how you might actually make use it

Comment: @Turing85, Ironic handle given that I'm not sure if your comment was auto generated by an algorithm searching questions for the word "library", but if you are not a bot and consider my question you'll observe that the whole point of it is that I am not finding "what has been done before to solve it" but am assuming that it does have a pre-existing solution; It is this solution that I'm seeking.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, ah, indeed that's precisely what I need... sadly it's all in Swing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Box2D](http://www.jbox2d.org/)

> **Features** 
>
> Rigid body physics 
> Stable stacking 
> Gravity 
> Fast persistent contact solver 
> Dynamic tree broadphase 
> Sliding friction 
> Boxes, circles, edges and **polygons** 
> Several joint types: distance, revolute, prismatic, pulley, gear, mouse 
> Motors
> Sleeping (removes motionless bodies from simulation until touched) 
> Continuous collision detection (accurate solving of fast bodies) 
> Ray casts 
> Sensors 
> Serialization 
> Dynamic, Kinematic, and Static bodies 
> Liquid particle simulation from Google's LiquidFun