# How to use paintComponent() without calling multiple "draw()" methods?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, paintcomponent

I'm new to java and I'm trying to create a "game".

In my game I have the paintComponent method within my main class:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setBackground(new Color(120,120,255));
    BackgroundObject.drawGrass(g,385);
    BackgroundObject.drawRoad(g,420);
    BackgroundObject.drawSun(g,-20,-20);
    myCar.draw(g);
    debugger.draw(g);
}
```

The problem is that every object I want to draw, I have to put it under the paintComponent method (like when I wanted to draw the car, I have to put myCar.draw() under paintComponent)

Is there any way do this?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setBackground(new Color(120,120,255));
    visualComponents.draw(g);
    GUI.draw(g);
}
```

where any class can tell the visualComponent class to draw an object when visualComponents.draw() is called.

Ex: 
My car class tells visualComponent to draw the vehicle whenever visualComponent.draw(g); is called.

To sum it up I am basically asking for the structure of how most people use paintComponent for their programs

I have been looking around google but couldn't find the answer.

If my question confuses you let me know.

Comment: Yes.  You can have the objects draw themselves.  See this article for an explanation and illustration.  http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=196

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might add the elements to a collection, then iterate the collection and draw each one in a loop.  That could paint 100s of objects within a few lines of code.

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14575043/418556) iterates a collection of `Area` instances & draws them using:

```
    for (Area obstacle : obstacles) {
        if (doAreasCollide(obstacle, player)) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        g.fill(obstacle);
    }
```

[image]

The 3 green & one red obstacles are in the collection, while the ball (small yellow circle) is drawn separately.

Comment: Thank you, I'll research into that.

Comment: Marking it accepted is all I need. Glad you got it sorted. :)