# Checking collision between Rectangle and Shape

Tags: java, collision-detection, shapes, rectangles, bounding-box

In my game the player uses a `Rectangle` for his bounding box, he can do this because I only need to rotate the player image and not the acctual rectangle but for a eletric beam that one of the bosses have I need to use a `Shape` because I need to rotate the acctual bounding box and not only the image. The problem is that because I have one `Rectangle` and one `Shape` I can't use `rectangle.intersect(shape)` nor `rectangle.intersect((Rectangle)shape)` so how would I be able to check the collision between the rectangle and the shape? or is there a way that I can rotate a rectangle on instead of a shape (I use the `createTransformedShape` instance of an `AffineTransform` to rotate the shape )?

Comment: `Rectangle` extends `Rectangle2D`.  `Shape` has a method called `intersects(Rectangle2D)` - Sorry, I might be missing something, it's late and I'm overdue for my nice warm bed :P.  `Rectangle` is also a `Shape`, via `Rectangle`->`Rectangle2D`->`RectangularShape`->`Shape`.  `Shape` has a method called `getBounds` which can return a `Rectangle` (or `getBounds2D` for a `Rectangle2D`)

Comment: A `Rectangle` **is a** `Shape`.  So [this source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574045/image-based-collision-detection/14575043#14575043) should work.