# Drawing In Java

Tags: java, swing, layout, graphics, jpanel

Hello I'm trying to do some drawing examples in `Java` using the `paintComponent` and the `Graphics` Object. I need a fixed size **'Stage' (400x300)** for the drawing and the `window/frame` **"around it"**.

Here is my setup:

```
public class MyJFrame extends JFrame{    
    public MyJFrame(){
        //setSize(new Dimension(400,300));
        setBackground(Color.green);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        add(stage);
        
        this.pack();
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
        
        System.out.println(this.size());
        System.out.println(stage.size()); 
    }
}

public class Stage extends JPanel {
    
    public Stage(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300));
        //setSize(new Dimension(400,300)); 
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 300); 
    }
}
```

Out put of the print is :

```
java.awt.Dimension[width=416,height=338]
java.awt.Dimension[width=400,height=300]
```

But the result looks like  this:
[image]

Black part is **400x300** .. not sure from where this extra spacing comes from.
I tried several variation of `setSize` `setPreferredSize` and layouts .. but nothing really worked.

P.S  any java fiddle out there?

Comment: Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one.

Answer (score 4):

```
//this.pack();
this.setResizable(false);
this.pack();
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things.

1. Call `pack` AFTER you `setResizable`.  This is a (not commonly) known bug
2. Don't rely on magic numbers.  You should be using known values where possible.  This will make your life easier should you decide to change these values later.

For example, instead of `g.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 300);` you should be using `g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());`

Comment: ty, have you any source  reference for this bug?
The numbers in the example are fixed just to make it more strict.

Comment: Mostly, this bug is from observation.  Try searching the site for `setResiable` ;)

Answer (score 2):

In this case I think you are better off using a [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) as the paint surface and simply displaying that in a [`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html).  A simple (animated) example can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14575043/418556).

[image]