# Making a ball bounce inside another ball

Tags: java, javafx-2, 2d, collision-detection, geometry

There is plenty of information about how to make balls collide with one another on their outer boundaries, but I couldn't find anything that covers **balls bouncing inside another ball**.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? I believe many people would benefit from this, including myself.

Comment: What specific problems are you facing? I think if you can implement normal ball collision, this wouldn't be very difficult.

Comment: What should that be any different?  If the inner ball collides with boundaries of the outer ball, it amounts to the same thing...Also what framework are you using, as this could affect the available APIs...

Comment: I'm not particularly familuar with JavaFx, but you might be able to use the `Shape` API from `java.awt`, which would allow to determine if one shape is within the bounds of another.  It would also allow you to translate the position of the `Shape` as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple using Java 2D.

```
/** A method to determine if area1 is entirely contained within area2. */
public boolean doAreasEnclose(Area area1, Area area2) {
    Area temp = new Area(area1);
    temp.subtract(area2);
    Rectangle r = temp.getBounds();
    boolean enclosed = r.getWidth()==0 && r.getHeight()==0;
    return enclosed;
}
```

The obstacle is shown:

- `GREEN` if not in contact with the player
- `ORANGE` if intersecting.
- **`RED` if entirely enclosing.**

### SSCCE

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ShapeContainment {

    private BufferedImage img;
    private Area[] obstacles = new Area[2];
    private Area walls;

    int x; 
    int y;
    int xDelta = 3;
    int yDelta = 2;

    /** A method to determine if area1 is entirely contained within area2. */
    public boolean doAreasEnclose(Area area1, Area area2) {
        Area temp = new Area(area1);
        temp.subtract(area2);
        Rectangle r = temp.getBounds();
        boolean enclosed = r.getWidth()==0 && r.getHeight()==0;
        return enclosed;
    }

    /** A method to determine if two instances of Area intersect */
    public boolean doAreasCollide(Area area1, Area area2) {
        boolean collide = false;

        Area collide1 = new Area(area1);
        collide1.subtract(area2);
        if (!collide1.equals(area1)) {
            collide = true;
        }

        Area collide2 = new Area(area2);
        collide2.subtract(area1);
        if (!collide2.equals(area2)) {
            collide = true;
        }

        return collide;
    }

    ShapeContainment() {
        int w = 400;
        int h = 200;
        img = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        final JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
        x = w/2;
        y = h/2;

        //circle 
        obstacles[0] = new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(40, 40, 60, 60));

        int[] xTriangle = {330,360,345};
        int[] yTriangle = {60,60,40};
        //triangle 
        obstacles[1] = new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(300, 100, 60, 60));

        walls = new Area(new Rectangle(0,0,w,h));

        ActionListener animate = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                animate();
                imageLabel.repaint();
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(50, animate);

        timer.start();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, imageLabel);
        timer.stop();
    }

    public void animate() {
        Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        x+=xDelta;
        y+=yDelta;
        int s = 15;
        Area player = new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, s, s));

        // Acid test of edge collision;
        if (doAreasCollide(player,walls)) {
            if ( x+s>img.getWidth() || x<0 ) {
                xDelta *= -1;
            } 
            if(y+s>img.getHeight() || y<0 ) {
                yDelta *= -1;
            }
        }
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        for (Area obstacle : obstacles) {
            if (doAreasEnclose(player, obstacle)) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
            } else if (doAreasCollide(obstacle, player)) {
                g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            g.fill(obstacle);
        }

        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fill(player);


        g.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ShapeContainment();
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Developed from code seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14575043/418556).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `intersects` method of the Node class to check for collision detection. What happens after the collision is up to you.

Docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#intersects