# Detect clicked card

Tags: java, swing, click, awt, mouselistener

Does anybody of You know a method to detect, which card on the board was clicked?
I got a class drawing multiple card objects on a `JPanel`.
Now I've implemented a `MouseAdapter`. On a mouse click it should check whether a card was clicked or not. Additionally it should tell me which object was clicked.

Any theoretical ideas, procedures or methods how to achieve this?

```
Card card = new Card();
public void paint(Graphics g) { 
    g.drawImage(card.getImage(), card.getX(), card.getY(), null); 
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ..but definitely look into using a sub-class of [`Rectangle2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html).  Since the parent class `implements Shape`, it can then be used just like seen in the example linked below.

Answer (score 2):

How do you draw the cards?  If using the Java-2D API and `Shape` instances, it can be quite easy.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14575043/418556) for an example of collision detection using complex shapes, then look closely at the [JavaDocs for `Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) for other methods that might help for determining if a `Point` is inside a shape.

[image]

Comment: I created a class called "Card". This card contains a BufferedImage.
The main core class with the JPanel contains the paint(Graphics g) method and looks as following:

public void paint(Graphics g) {
g.drawImage(card.getImage(), card.getX(), card.getY(), null);
}

Thats a simplified example how the drawing works

Comment: Oops sorry forgot about all that. Edited my post!