# How can I make an element that uses mouse adapter?

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener

I want to make an element for a game that glows when mouse enters/exits and mouse click can be performed on it. I know abaut MoseAdapter and Listener, but when I implement MouseListener the element doesn't do anything. From what should I extend it from or implement it? I made it work using 2 for loops to check where was the mouse clicked - in a panel where all the elements ar positioned and painted - but that's a waste of memory/time.

```
public class GElement {

private int size=30;
private int x=0;
private int y=0;
private int width=size;
private int height=size;

private int minesNear=0;
private boolean visible=false;
private boolean flagged=false;
private boolean mined=false;

public GElement() {}
public GElement(int x, int y) {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.width=size;
    this.height=size;
}

public void paintIt(Graphics2D g2) {

    if(flagged) {
        g2.setColor(new Color(0,150,0));
    } else if(!visible) {
        g2.setColor(new Color(0,0,250));
    } else if(mined) {
        g2.setColor(new Color(150,0,0));
    } else {
        g2.setColor(new Color(0,0,50));
    }
    g2.fillRect(x,y,width,height);
}
}
```

This element is drawed in a panel whit it's paintComponent.

```
public GamePane(int r, int c, int m) {
        this.rows=r;
        this.cols=c;
        this.mines=m;

        // Mine field setter
        posX=offset;
        posY=offset;
        eArray=new GElement[rows][cols];
        GElement e=new GElement();
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++) {
                e=new GElement(posX,posY);
                posX+=e.getWidth()+offset;
                eArray[i][j]=e;
            }
            width=posX-10;
            posX=offset;
            posY+=e.getWidth()+offset;
        }
        height=posY-10;

        // Standard properties
        this.bgColor=new Color(0,0,150);
        this.setOpaque(true);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
        // Background
        g2.setColor(bgColor);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, width+10, height+10);
        // Rest
        // TODO
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++) {
                eArray[i][j].paintIt(g2);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The GamePane is set as the contentPane of the main frame. Thank you!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In your GamePanel, add a MouseListerner to it. As the mouse moves check to see if it moves over any of the elements you're interested in. Maintain some kind of list indicating which elements should be highlighted.  When painting, paint the highlight first...

Comment: Oh, but see also [Collision detection with complex shapes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14575043/418556).  It is only a short step from collision detection to determining if a point is within a `Shape`..

Comment: Thank you! I will try Collison detection. Hope I can figure it out.