# Detect the collision point of two objects

Tags: java, applet, awt, collision-detection, java-2d

I have a program with a `Ellipse2D` (which is a circle) and a `Polygon` object. I have decided to use the collision detection solution [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574045/collision-detection-with-complex-shapes/14575043#comment33922612_14575043) to handle the detection of collisions.

I want the circle object to remain on top of the polygon at all times.

I now know when the `Ellipse2D` object intersects the polygon, but I would like to know WHERE they intersect. I don't currently know of any way to detect how high the circle object should move in order to remain on top of the polygon.

My intent is to move the circle upwards to always remain "on top" of the polygon when the two objects move toward each other horizontally.

[image]

Is there a tool or method out there that I am not aware of that returns a collision point or is this something I will have to develop on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract one `Area` from the other.  The `Bounds` of the resulting area will represent the *overlap* between the two objects.  The center of the overlapping `Bounds` will most likely either be the collision point, or so close as to fool the viewer into thinking it is.