# How to make my collision check with Intersect between rectangles to work?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, intersect, breakout

EDIT:here is the full code: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65678182/assignment1.rar Any possible help is highly appreciated!

---

I am trying to make a copy of the breakout game, but I have problems with checking if two objects (the ball and paddle) intersects.

I have this method for collision detection for now:

```
public static void handleCollisions()
    {

        System.out.println(ball.getBounds());        // just to check that they                  
        System.out.println(paddle.getBounds());      //are there and moving correct

        if (ball.getBounds().intersects(paddle.getBounds()))
            {
        System.out.println("collision");
            }
    }
```

I'm pretty sure the getBounds works as they should since I get these outputs from the println: 
java.awt.Rectangle[x=393,y=788,width=14,height=14]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=350,y=350,width=100,height=10]

```
getBounds code:
    public static Rectangle getBounds()
    {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, radius*2, radius*2);                     
    }
```

and I can see them moving at one point they are overlapping, but the method never detects it.

I'm pretty new to this so hopefully its just some stupid mistake somewhere, and any help is appreciated. I can post some more code if necessary, but would prefer to not.

Comment: `Rectangle.intersects()` works and what you have shown us so far seems OK. The problem is elsewhere, in parts that you have not shown us. For example, are you sure you are actually calling `handleCollisions()` when you should be? Are you sure that `ball` and `paddle` correctly refer to the objects in question? When you print out their bounding box values at every frame, do you actually see them overlap? Try, as a test, initializing your ball position to directly on top of your paddle, and disabling movement; this will make it easier to see if your collision detection is working.

Comment: If the output you've shown us is your *only* output then that suggests that you are not calling `handleCollisions()` on every frame, because you would expect to see more than one print out (plus the example you showed us doesn't actually intersect, but I'm assuming that's because it was just an arbitrary example).

Comment: Got a runnable example?

Comment: @Jason I can see the ball moving towards the paddle, then over it.  Tried to move the ball to paddle and not movement, still no detection even though i can see the ball on top of the paddle visually.

Comment: is there any way to pm? could give the program to you then MadProgrammer

Comment: See [Collision detection with complex shapes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14574045/418556) for a robust approach in which Java-2D does all the 'heavy lifting'.

Comment: I suppose you could just post a link to it here or something.

Comment: just did that, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 3):

```
java.awt.Rectangle[x=393,y=788,width=14,height=14] 
java.awt.Rectangle[x=350,y=350,width=100,height=10]
```

As you can see the second rectangle's y/height 350/10 but the first's y=788

Obviously they have no intersection one is above another

UPDATE
One more thing

```
public static Rectangle getBounds()
{
    return new Rectangle(x, y, radius*2, radius*2);                     
}
```

If x and y are the ball's center the code should be

```
public static Rectangle getBounds()
{
    return new Rectangle(x-radius, y-radius, radius*2, radius*2);                     
}
```

Comment: Going out a limb here, but I suspect thats just example output the op is getting dumped to the stdout..just saying...

Comment: Yeah it was just an example, i do get a outprint every step and they seem to be moving right, corresponding to what i can see on the screen

Comment: the x and y is the top left corner of the rectangle around the ball