# Java intersects method not working Properly

Tags: java, swing

Could someone please tell me why my code does not work Properly?

I am trying to make the colour change when I move over it but its just not working.

I'm using the intersects method.

```
package com.dilkiel.game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Screen extends JPanel implements Runnable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Thread thread;

public int tickCount = 0;
public boolean running = false;
public int xPlayerOffset = 100;
public int yPlayerOffset = 100;
public int WIDTH = 1280;
public int HEIGHT = 720;

public InputHandler input = new InputHandler(this);

public Screen() {
    setFocusable(true);
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    start();
}

public void tick() {
    tickCount++;
    if (input.up.isPressed()) {
        yPlayerOffset -= 5;
    }
    if (input.down.isPressed()) {
        yPlayerOffset += 5;
    }
    if (input.left.isPressed()) {
        xPlayerOffset -= 5;
    }
    if (input.right.isPressed()) {
        xPlayerOffset += 5;
    }
}

public synchronized void start() {
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Game Loop");
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Image frontView = new ImageIcon("res/frontView.png").getImage();
Rectangle player = new Rectangle(xPlayerOffset, yPlayerOffset + 40, 40, 40);
Rectangle box = new Rectangle(250, 250, 80, 80);

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    g.drawImage(frontView, xPlayerOffset, yPlayerOffset, this);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    if (player.intersects(box)) {
        //i want this to work can you please show me how. Thanks
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    g.fillRect(xPlayerOffset, yPlayerOffset + 40, 40, 40);
    g.fillRect(250, 250, 80, 80);
    g.dispose();
}

public void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double nsPerTick = 1000000000D / 60D;

    int ticks = 0;
    int frames = 0;

    long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double delta = 0;

    while (running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / nsPerTick;
        lastTime = now;
        boolean shouldRender = false;

        while (delta >= 1) {
            ticks++;
            tick();
            delta -= 1;
            shouldRender = true;
        }
        /*
         * try { Thread.sleep(2); } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         * e.printStackTrace(); }
         */
        if (shouldRender) {
            frames++;
            repaint();
        }

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer >= 1000) {
            lastTimer += 1000;

            System.out.println(ticks + ", " + frames);
            frames = 0;
            ticks = 0;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where is `InputHandler` defined?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14574045/418556) for an approach that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I addressed some points that might help you.

1. Use  [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead of `Thread`

   Learn more [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
2. Override `paintComponent()` method for custom painting instead of overriding `paint()` method.
3. Don't forget to call `super.paintComponent()` in overridden method.
4. Override [JComponent#getPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize%28%29) instead of using `setPreferredSize()`

   Learn more [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

---

Sample code: (*Custom painting in JPanel*)

```
final JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // your custom painting code here
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(..., ...);
    }
};
```

Sample code: (*Swing Timer*)

```
// wait for 1 second
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {            
        // next call 
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start()
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try and use you method if it works i'll get back to you

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using intersect method , you can add an on Mouse hover listener and write the code to change the colour within it which is better as it gives you more control and response.

Comment: i want to use a character that is an image not the mouse sorry.