# Add MouseListener wihout extend Swing Component

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I'am trying to make a little game for academic stuff. What I want to do is to make a random number of balls move inside a `JPanel`, with random directions, but when I click inside of the ball it should sysout the actual coords of the ball. Here is my class without the move methods (I already made it but don't need to post it for this question):

```
public class Ball implements Runnable {

    int x = UserInterface.BALL_START; 
    int y = 0;
    int size  = 10;     
    Color color;

    public Ball() {
        Random random = new Random();    
        int r, g, b;
        r = random.nextInt(256);
        g = random.nextInt(256);
        b = random.nextInt(256);
        color = new Color(r,g,b);
        y = random.nextInt(500);
    }

    public void run() {
        int vx = (new Random()).nextInt(10) + 1;                
        while (x < UserInterface.BALL_END) {
            x += vx;            
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        x = UserInterface.BALL_END;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)  {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(x - size / 2, y - size / 2, size, size);     
    }
}
```

How can I add a mouselistener to the ball class without make it as a `JComponent` or `JLabel` or `JPanel`?

Comment: What ever is calling `paint`, should be registered as the `MouseListener`, it should then talk with the ball to figure out where it is and do what ever else you need it to

Comment: `public void paint(Graphics g)  {` missing `super.paint`

Comment: @mKorbel don't miss the super cause I don't extended nothing

Comment: The documentation of the class [`AWTEventMulticaster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AWTEventMulticaster.html) has an example for implementing an event source. Of course, you need a mechanism to forward the component’s mouse events to the ball instance…

Comment: See MadProgrammers's comment! In addition, you need to ensure the mouse coords from your mouse click are in the correct coordinate system, then get the Ball to create a Shape and use "contains" on it to check if your click has "hit" the ball.

Comment: Are you sure you want each of your balls to be running in their own thread?

Comment: @Kayaman I just want multiple balls moving random, and when I select one of them it should print the actual coords of the ball

Comment: @niarb 1. (you comment about  don't extended nothing) nothing will be painted, 2. I just want multiple balls moving random - use Swing Timer, 1-5k good ideas with code examples in SSCCE/MCVE form are here,

Comment: @MadProgrammer, what you are saying is that I should have a class named BallsZone (extends JPanel), and this class should have a mouselistener to check if any ball has been clicked?

Comment: Something is painting the, somewhere, there is some kind of component, that should have the MouseListener

Answer (score 1):

See [Collision detection with complex shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14575043/418556) & replace the small moving ball with the mouse position and tweak the collision code for an `Area` and a `Point` using [`Area.contains(Point2D)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html#contains-java.awt.geom.Point2D-).

[image]

That code renders the visible part to an image displayed in a label.  Display the label in a container/layout/constraint that preserves the size, and we can add the mouse listener directly to the label.