# How to implement a smoothly falling JLabel without using Timer, but Threads instead

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sleep

Alright, so I have a null layout `JPanel` with a single `JLabel` in it. The `JLabel` is positioned at (0,0). What I'm trying to do is use a while loop in a new `Thread` to sleep the new `Thread` and then shift the `JLabel` 10px down by using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` . The problem is that the UI gets updated in a laggy sort of way. It doesn't update every time it should, but skips lots of updates and shifts in big chunks. I know I can easily do it with `Timer`, but the point is understanding `Threads` better. Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
private void start(){
    Updater up = new Updater();
    up.start();
}
public void updatePosition(){
    int y = label1.getLocation.y;
    label.setBounds(0,y+10, 10,10);
}
private class Updater extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        while(!shouldQuit){
            try{
                Updater.sleep(100);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                       updatePosition(); 
                    }
                }); 
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }      
        }   
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I got it to work by replacing the while loop with a call to a new Thread instance in the `updatePosition()` method, to settle things down a bit. And also, it wasn't only the Thread that was causing the problem, so I had to force the panel to re-layout it's subviews by calling `revalidate()` on it.
Here's how it looks (the fully working one):

```
private void start(){
    new Updater().start();
}
public void updatePosition(){
    int y = label1.getLocation.y;
    label.setBounds(0,y+10, 10,10);
    panel.revalidate();
    if(!shouldQuit) new Updater().start();
}
private class Updater extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        try{
            Updater.sleep(100);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    updatePosition(); 
                }
            }); 
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: *"How to implement a smoothly falling JLabel without using Timer, but Threads instead"*  Why 'without timer'?  Why also not do this in a custom painted panel, instead of trying to position a component on the fly?

Comment: Timer is based on Threads, so I figure there should be a way to do it, and  it's just a problem I don't know the solution to, so that makes it worth solving. How would you suggest I do it in a custom painted panel?

Comment: *"How would you suggest I do it in a custom painted panel?"*  Much like [this animation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14575043/418556) but painting strings instead of shapes.  Actually (checks) that uses a `BufferedImage` instead of a custom panel.  But it's the same principal once you have a `Graphics` instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll look into it. However, I just can't understand why the JLabel doesn't update on every updatePosition() call.... I feel like I'm missing something essential...

Comment: Side note:  It is good practice for your try/catch to be around your `while` loop rather than inside it.  If some other code sends your Thread an interrupt, it means you're being requested to stop what you're doing.  Putting the loop inside the try/catch is the easiest way to properly respond to that.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use visibility and GridLayout to maximize movement. You can use a int var to count threads and reciprocate that to the label. As well, you should be using your ability o create Updaters, more and smoother. Just do the start() mwthod while trolling for threads :-)

You could have something besides an infinity call to start. I think you've lost the inheritance from the class, itself. The object `label1` must ave been lost in tbe fray. If that's not it, then I'm pretty sure I'm not really able to answer this one.