# How do detect collision for a complex shape like a game character?

Tags: javascript, html

for a simple rectangle, i would use:

```
if(ballX > rectX && ballX < rectX + rectWidth && ballY > rectY && ballY <rectY  + rectHeight) {
alert("Game over");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions isn't really a javascript or html question directly but..

1) There are multiple options how to detect if two objects are colliding. One (and simple) solution is called AABB Collision Detection ([good video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghqD3e37R7E))

2) There is a good Answer already on stackoverflow: [Collision detection with complex shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574045/collision-detection-with-complex-shapes)

3) There are plenty of good game frameworks ([take a look at this list](https://html5gameengine.com/)) doing collision detection for you. Are you sure you want to do it by your own?