# Collision between a ball and a rectangle

Tags: java, awt, java-2d

I was required to change the direction of a ball according to the collision between the ball and a rectangle.

That's my code:

```
 public Velocity hit(Point collisionPoint, Velocity currentVelocity) {
    Velocity newVelocity = currentVelocity;

    // starting point - according to the upper left point of the rectangle
    double startX = rectangle.getUpperLeft().getX();
    double startY = rectangle.getUpperLeft().getY();

    double x = collisionPoint.getX();
    double y = collisionPoint.getY();

    // Y direction
    if ((x > startX) &&
            (x < startX + rectangle.getWidth())) {
        newVelocity.setDy((currentVelocity.getDy()) * (-1));
    }
    // X direction
    else if ((y > startY) &&
            (y < startY + rectangle.getWidth())) {
        newVelocity.setDx(currentVelocity.getDx() * (-1));
    }
    // hits the corners
    else {
        newVelocity.setDx(currentVelocity.getDx() * (-1));
        newVelocity.setDy(currentVelocity.getDy() * (-1));
    }

    return newVelocity;
}
```

Explanation:
"hit" is a function that gets the collision point and the velocity of the ball.
This function is called just in the case of a hit. In the function I checked if the ball hits the right and left walls of the rectangle, the bottom or tom or else - the corners.

```
public void moveOneStep() {

    Velocity currentVelocity = this.getVelocity();
    double collisionHeight;
    double collisionWidth;

    // starting point - according to surface
    double collisionStartX;
    double collisionStartY;

    double x = this.center.getX();
    double y = this.center.getY();

    Line trajectory = new Line(new Point(x, y), 
    new Point(x + currentVelocity.getDx(), 
    y + currentVelocity.getDy()));


    // get the closest collision point between the line and the rectangle
    CollisionInfo collisionInfo = this.gameEnvironment.getClosestCollision(trajectory);

    if (collisionInfo != null) {
        // there's a collision
        currentVelocity = collisionInfo.collisionObject().
        hit(collisionInfo.collisionPoint(), currentVelocity);
    } else {
        collisionHeight = this.surface.getHeight();
        collisionWidth = this.surface.getWidth();
        collisionStartX = this.surface.getStartingPoint().getX();
        collisionStartY = this.surface.getStartingPoint().getY();
        // X direction
        if ((x + currentVelocity.getDx() > collisionWidth - 
            radius - 1 + collisionStartX)
                || (x + currentVelocity.getDx() < radius + collisionStartX)) {
            currentVelocity.setDx((currentVelocity.getDx()) * (-1));
        }
        // Y direction
        if ((y + currentVelocity.getDy() > collisionHeight - 
           radius - 1 + collisionStartY) ||
                (y + currentVelocity.getDy() < radius + collisionStartY)) {
            currentVelocity.setDy(currentVelocity.getDy() * (-1));
        }

    }

    this.setVelocity(currentVelocity);

    this.center = this.velocity.applyToPoint(this.center);
}
```

Explanation: The ball moves according to a line. I check in each step if the line has a collision point with the rectangle.

**I have a problem, the ball get inside the rectangle a little bit. How can I change that?**

Thank you

Comment: I think there's too little to tell from your code, but are you perhaps treating the circle and /or square as points, and not taking into account the radius of the circle or the width of square? 
If so they won't "collide" until those points hit, which will mean your shapes overlap before they bounce.

Comment: Probably, the problem is with the code which determines when a 'hit' occurred, and not the change in velocity.

Comment: Ok thank you. I added the "move one step" function. In this function I call "hit" in the case of a collision

Comment: I think the problem is in the line trajectory, because sometimes the line is shorter than the radius. How can I define the line according to the radius? Thank you

Comment: you have to show the collision code

Comment: See [Collision detection with complex shapes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14575043/418556) for a working example of effective collision detection.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) (e.g. as seen in the collision detection code linked in my first comment).