# Change ball color when colliding

Tags: java, swing

I'm making an java app (for exercise) where there must be a panel and 2 buttons.

1. Each time you press the start button a ball must be displayed and it moves based on thread. The user can display all the way up to 10 independent balls.
2. By pressing the stop button, 1 ball must be removed with  each time the stop button is pressed (example, when there is 4 balls, the user must press 4 times stop button to remove all the balls independently)
3. All the x- and y coordinates of the balls must be stored in a Matrix
4. When 1 or more ball(s) are colliding with each other, only the colliding balls must change color from red to blue

Ok I'm almost done with it completely ( from point 1 to 4 ), but here comes my problem. When a ball is colliding with another, instead of changing the colors of the colliding balls to blue, my code is changing all the balls color from red to blue. I know that my error lies at the `new Balls().setColor(Color.Blue)`, but I have no idea how to change only the colliding balls.

Below follows a screen shot of the java app and the code.
Can anyone help me with this headache?

Printscreen: [image]

source code:

```
import java.awt.Color;             
import java.awt.Dimension;    
import java.awt.FlowLayout;   
import java.awt.Graphics;    
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;   
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;   
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  
import javax.swing.JButton;    
import javax.swing.JFrame;    
import javax.swing.JLabel;  
import javax.swing.JPanel;`


public class BouncingBalls extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

protected List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>(10);
private final Container container;
private final DrawCanvas canvas;
private  int canvasWidth;
private  int canvasHeight;
public JButton start, stop;
int [][] coords= new int[11][2];
int ammountOfBalls = 0;
static Color clr= Color.RED;


public static int random(int maxRange) {
    return (int) Math.round((Math.random() * maxRange));
}

public BouncingBalls(int width, int height) {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     start= new JButton("start");
    start.addActionListener(this);
     stop= new JButton("stop");
    stop.addActionListener(this);
    add(start);
    add(stop);
    add(new JLabel(""));
    container = new Container();
    canvasWidth = width;
    canvasHeight = height;
    canvas = new DrawCanvas();
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.add(canvas);
    start();

}

public void start() {

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (true) {

                update();
                getPositions();
                collisionDetection();
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }

        private void collisionDetection() {
            // The algorithm  that detects collision
          for(int i=0;i<ammountOfBalls;i++){
            for(int j=i+1; j<ammountOfBalls; j++){
                  if(collisionMethod(i,j)){  // my collision method
                      //HOW DO I CHANGE ONLY THE COLLIDING BALLS COLOR HERE????
                     new Ball().setColor(Color.BLUE);  // this line here changes the color of all the balls on the panel
                      System.out.println("Its a hit");
                  }
              }

           }  

        }

        private void getPositions() {
            int row=0;
            for (Ball ball : balls) {
             int x =ball.getXPosition();
             int y =ball.getYPosition();
             coords[row][0]=x;
             coords[row][1]=y;
             row++;
            }

        }

        private boolean collisionMethod(int i, int j) {
           float xd = coords[i][0]-coords[j][0];
           float yd=coords[i][1]-coords[j][1];
           float radius= new Ball().ballRadius;
           float sqrRadius= radius * radius;
           float distSqr= (xd * xd) + (yd * yd);

           if(distSqr <= sqrRadius)
               return true;

            return false;
        }
      };
    t.start();
}

public void update() {
    for (Ball ball : balls) {
        ball.move(container);
    }
 }

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == start){
        if(ammountOfBalls < 10){
            // to limit the ammount of balls to 10
            balls.add(new Ball());
            ammountOfBalls++;
       }
    }

    else if( e.getSource() == stop){
        if(ammountOfBalls > 0){
      ammountOfBalls --;
      balls.remove(ammountOfBalls);

    }

    }
}

class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        container.draw(g);
        for (Ball ball : balls) {
            ball.draw(g);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return (new Dimension(700, 400));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Bouncing Balls");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,500));
            f.setContentPane(new BouncingBalls(800,800));
            f.pack();
            f.setVisible(true);
    }


public static class Ball {

    public int random(int maxRange) {
        return (int) Math.round(Math.random() * maxRange);
    }

int x = random(700); // method to get random coords for the x-value
int y = random(400); // method to get random coords for the y-value  ...... these are used to get random positions for the balls instead of only static
int xMovement = 10;
int yMovement = 10;
int ballRadius = 20;
int i = 0;


public Color getColor(){
  return clr;
}
public Color setColor(Color color){
clr=color;
return clr;
}
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(getColor());
        g.fillOval(x,y,ballRadius,ballRadius);

    }
    public int getXPosition(){
        return x;
    }
    public int getYPosition(){
        return y;
    }

    public void move(Container container) {
        x += xMovement;
        y += yMovement;

        if (x - ballRadius < 0) {
            xMovement = -xMovement;
            x = ballRadius;
        } 
        else if (x + ballRadius > 700) {
            xMovement = -xMovement;
            x = 700 - ballRadius;
        }

        if (y - ballRadius < 0) {
            yMovement = -yMovement;
            y = ballRadius;
        } 
        else if (y + ballRadius > 400) {
            yMovement = -yMovement;
            y = 400 - ballRadius;
        }
    }
}



public static class Container {
    private static final int hightPanel = 800;
    private static final int widthPanel=  800;

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, widthPanel, hightPanel);
    }
}
}
```

`

Comment: You have to identify which balls are actually colliding. Seems like an odd method of dealing with objects' coordinates separated from the visual representation of them.

Comment: See also [Collision detection with complex shapes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14575043/418556) for a working example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined `clr` as a static field of your application. When your `Ball` class calls `setColor()` you are changing the value of `clr` to blue... and then any `Ball` that calls `getColor()` will see that `clr` is blue.

Solution: Don't make `clr` an application-wide static field. Define it in the `Ball` class as a non-static field, so each `Ball` has its own color.

Comment: Good eye. I think they have additional issues as well. They create a new ball on collision and don't actually have the balls that are colliding; only their coordinates.

Comment: thank you very much for the help.. it's working perfectly now