# Why is my collision not working 100% of the time in my attempt at a pong game?

Tags: java, libgdx, collision

I am using Libgdx to create a simple pong game with JAVA and when using two rectangles as my objects that will be colliding (ball and paddle/player) the ball often goes through my paddle, though sometimes it works and bounces back when it overlaps with each other.

I've tried doing it without using Rectangle.Overlap() but the same issue arises (if not worse).

Here is what my "Ball" class looks like :

```
Vector2 position;
Vector2 velocity;


Player player;


boolean gameStart = false;

public static final String TAG = Ball.class.getName();


public Ball() {
    player = new Player();
    init();
}


public void init(){
    position = new Vector2(100,100);
    velocity = new Vector2();

}

private void ballKick(){
    Random random = new Random();
    float angleX = MathUtils.PI2 * random.nextFloat();
    float angleY = MathUtils.PI * random.nextFloat();
    velocity.x = Constants.BALL_KICK_VELOICTY * MathUtils.cos(angleX);
    velocity.y = Constants.BALL_KICK_VELOICTY * MathUtils.sin(angleY);
}

public void update(float delta, Viewport viewport){



    if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE) && gameStart == false){
        ballKick();
        gameStart = true;
        if (velocity.y < 100){
            velocity.y = 100;
        }

    }

   position.mulAdd(velocity,delta);

   collision(viewport);
}


public void render(ShapeRenderer renderer){

    renderer.setAutoShapeType(true);
    renderer.setColor(Constants.BALL_COLOR);
    renderer.set(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    renderer.circle(position.x,position.y,Constants.BALL_RADIUS,Constants.BALL_SEGMENTS);
    {



private void collision(Viewport viewport){

    // WALL COLLISION
    //Bottom Side

    //Top Side
    if (position.y + Constants.BALL_RADIUS > viewport.getWorldHeight()){
        position.y = viewport.getWorldHeight() - Constants.BALL_RADIUS;
        velocity.y = -velocity.y;
    }
    // Left Side
    if (position.x - Constants.BALL_RADIUS < 0){
        position.x = Constants.BALL_RADIUS;
        velocity.x = -velocity.x ;
    }
    // Right Side
    if (position.x + Constants.BALL_RADIUS > viewport.getWorldWidth()){
        position.x = viewport.getWorldWidth() - Constants.BALL_RADIUS;
        velocity.x = -velocity.x ;
    }

    //PLAYER COLLISION
    Rectangle ballBounds = new Rectangle(position.x - Constants.BALL_RADIUS,position.y - Constants.BALL_RADIUS,Constants.BALL_RADIUS * 2, Constants.BALL_RADIUS * 2);
    Rectangle playerBounds = new Rectangle(player.position.x , player.position.y , Constants.PLAYER_WIDTH, Constants.PLAYER_HEIGHT);

    if (ballBounds.overlaps(playerBounds)){
            position.y = player.position.y + Constants.BALL_RADIUS + Constants.PLAYER_HEIGHT;
            velocity.y = -velocity.y;
            Gdx.app.log(TAG, "It overlapped");

    }

}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work properly as I have used this method in a different game and it seemed to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

I forgot to update the player in the ball class so the ball only knew it's starting position and thus only bounced off when it happened to land on the paddles starting position whether my paddle was still there or not. It is working now, thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: If you ball is traveling fast enough it could be on one side of the paddle on one frame and the other on the next. Your code is assuming the ball will happen to overlap with the paddle on a graphics frame. The solution is to break up your physics into a fixed time and update your simulation multiple times per frame I'd the graphics delta time is too big. Or you could draw a ray from the ball's old position to new position and intersect the ray with the paddle.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See also [Collision detection with complex shapes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14575043/418556).