# Can't detect collision with Polygon

Tags: java, list, swing, collision-detection, polygon

Some context- its an Asteroids game

I'm trying to detect collision between a circle and a Polygon object, so I'm using Polygon.contains() with the circle's coordinates.
but for some unknown reason only sometimes it actually detecting a collision:
when the first meteor (polygon) appears I'll try to shoot it (the bullet is the circle) and it *may* detect it but not for sure same goes for the second and so on- in other words the detection not always work.

The code:

```
 public void run() {
        super.run();
        while (true){
            decreaseArr(this.shapes[0].xpoints,1);
                if (!Bullet.bulletList.isEmpty()){
                    for (int i = 0; i< Bullet.bulletList.size() ; i++){
                            Bullet currentBullet= Bullet.bulletList.get(i);
                            if (this.shapes[0].contains(currentBullet.x, currentBullet.y)){
                                System.out.println(meteorList.indexOf(this));
                                System.out.println("HIT!");
                                Bullet.bulletList.remove(currentBullet); //Delete bullet from screen
                                meteorList.remove(this); //Delete from screen
                                breakFlag=true;
                                System.out.println(Meteor.meteorList);
                            }
                    }
                    if (breakFlag)
                        break;
                }
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(meteorVelocity);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

(That's the run method inside the Meteor class so each meteor has a shapes array (and now it only has one shape but later on I'll add more))

EDIT:
[Some video footage](https://vimeo.com/659040692) (sorry for not editing earlier, just came home :))

EDIT 2:

Important note:
each time I run the game chances are I *wont* be able to destroy the same meteors as previous time- each time I get different results

Comment: I don't see a list of `Polygon` instances, nor do I see a call to the `Polygon` `intersects` method.

Comment: Is your bullet moving fast enough that it may possibly “warp through” a meteor?

Comment: [Edit] to add a [mre] like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14575043/418556), which incidentally, is about collision detection with complex (Java-2D) shapes. In fact, run that code first to check it does as you expect, then try to adapt the methods into your own code. If ***that*** fails, add your best attempt here as an MRE.

Comment: Yeah I wrote the post in class and couldn't take photos
Just was about to edit it :)

Comment: @VGR
the bullet is not nearly as fast to just "pass by" (Checked it)

Comment: @AndrewThompson just added some video footage so you can see :)

Comment: *"just added some video footage so you can see"* I don't read SO just to go off watching videos. Where is your MRE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After any changes made to Polygon invalidate() must be called

Comment: Add it as a comment