# how to add an array of blocks in java for a minecraft 2d like game

Tags: java, swing

I've seen someone do it in a video but never understood how to make an array of blocks instead of coding each block itself. please explain how i can make rows and columns of blocks. i already can draw them but cannot draw multiple ones. if you can, explain how to add layers of blocks from my block class.

To make a block i made a block class wich image is a block of dirt. then it has a method returning a new rectangle called getbounds. i use g2d.drawImage(block.getImage(), block.x, block.y, null); tto draw one block, but what can i do for multiple ones?

Comment: Could you edit your question to show us how you draw a single block right now?

Comment: Usually, what's done is to separate the information about locations of blocks from the logic that paints a block at a particular location. Then just loop through your table of blocks and call the paintBlockAtThisLocation subroutine for each one of them.

Comment: @keshlam thanks i'll try that but can you still give an example.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22507549/2587435) might be of interest to you.

Comment: Possibly related examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11553461/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following *untested* code should help. You will have to set 'observer' to an appropriate value. If you can't set 'observer' correctly, trying guessing the height and width of your image.

```
ImageObserver observer = _appropriate_value_here_;
Image image = block.getImage();
int BLOCK_X_DIM = image.getHeight(observer);   // The height of a block
int BLOCK_Y_DIM = image.getWidth(observer);    // The width of a block
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        g2d.drawImage(image, BLOCK_X_DIM * i, BLOCK_Y_DIM * j, null);
    }
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you very much and i love the Happy coding at the end :D. I've needed to know how to use for loops for a while and this was great!

Comment: Sadly, I don't know. In fact, I've never used them myself. Every time I come across a new object or class I haven't encountered (this is VERY common), I try to Google it and look up the documentation. If you are new to programming, I really recommend doing that ALWAYS! The documentation for the ImageObserver is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/ImageObserver.html. Also, see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html) page. It looks like the observer can be null if your Image is of type 'BufferedImage'

Comment: thanks for the tip and much more