# JFrame the same shape as an Image / Program running in background

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, shapes

My question is simple, the solution surely not. I am looking for a way to shape a JFrame the same as an Image it will be displaying. By shape I mean the shape of the pixels that have an alpha != 0. I've already found a working example using a GeneralPath object, but it created ~110000 "nodes" for an Image of about 500*400, so starting the JFrame took more than 2 minutes, which is definitely not the desired effect, the startup should be in under 2 seconds.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This might help: [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html). But of course the main problem is you still need to retrieve image shape, this might help with that: [Image/Graphic into a Shape in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7059497/1133011)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I personally would ditch the window shape in favor of a transparent window, it's just simpler for what you are trying to do...

[image]

And with the close button (look to the bottom left)

[image]

The red border around the image is deliberate, as it shows the "window" bounds.

This relies on either Java 1.7 or Java 1.6_10+, there are checks in the code.

```
public class TransparentFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TransparentFrame();
    }

    public TransparentFrame() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setContentPane(new ContentPane());

                String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
                System.out.println(version);
                if (version.startsWith("1.7")) {
                    frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                } else if (version.startsWith("1.6")) {
                    if (supportsPerAlphaPixel()) {
                        setOpaque(frame, false);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Per Pixel Alphering is not support with Java " + version);
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Per Pixel Alphering is not support with Java " + version);
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ImagePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static boolean supportsPerAlphaPixel() {

        boolean support = false;

        try {

            Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
            support = true;

        } catch (Exception exp) {
        }

        return support;

    }

    public static void setOpaque(Window window, boolean opaque) {

        try {

            Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
            if (awtUtilsClass != null) {

                Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("setWindowOpaque", Window.class, boolean.class);
                method.invoke(null, window, opaque);

            }

        } catch (Exception exp) {
        }

    }

    public class ContentPane extends JPanel {

        public ContentPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
        }
    }

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;
        private BufferedImage offImage;
        private Ellipse2D offButton;
        private boolean mouseIn;

        public ImagePane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(new File("tamagotchi400.png"));
                offImage = ImageIO.read(new File("powerSmall.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            offButton = new Ellipse2D.Float(212, 330, 25, 25);
            MouseAdapter handler = new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.getClickCount() == 1 && e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                        if (offButton.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                            Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(ImagePane.this);
                            if (window != null) {
                                window.dispose();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    Cursor cursor = Cursor.getDefaultCursor();
                    if (offButton.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                        cursor = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
                    }
                    setCursor(cursor);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    mouseIn = true;
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    mouseIn = false;
                    repaint();
                }
            };
            addMouseListener(handler);
            addMouseMotionListener(handler);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return background == null ? new Dimension(400, 400) : new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (background != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(background, x, y, this);
                if (mouseIn && offImage != null) {
                    g2d.drawImage(offImage, (int) offButton.getX(), (int) offButton.getY(), this);
                }
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 very nice example but i must ask why do you check for per pixel translucency via checking java version and classes etc, would `isWindowTranslucencySupported(PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT)` be better see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html#capability)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp `isWindowTranslucencySupported` is only supported in Java 7.  Under Java 6 I need to follow a different API path, but, it's only available after Java 1.6 update 10, hence the use of reflection.  Under Java 7 I should actually use `isWindowTranslucencySupported` as well and I will endeavour to add that into my library code, cheers :D

Answer (score 3):

I could not understand your first question. My English is not so good and this could be the reason.

About the second question, have you tried something about TrayIcon? Please, take e look: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html

Comment: Thanks, but I already found those links you posted.
About the first question: Let's say I'm making something like a PC-Tamagotchi. For that, I have a background image shaped like the "oldschool" Tamagotchi controllers. This image is of a non-rectangular shape, and I don't want the JFrame outlines visible around the image. This is why I need the JFrame to adapt to the image.

Comment: A shaped frame won't display the border or title bar (as you've clipped the frame), personally, I think you're better off using a transparent frame

Comment: @MadProgrammer thiught if that, why OP doesn't just create transparent frame thus making the interface of tamagotchi visible while background of Jframe invisible . +1 good suggestion

Comment: @MadProgrammer thought about it some more if you have a look at an installation menu like starcraft 2 the window is completely shaped and they manually add icons for exit minimize etc so I guess thats what the OP is trying to achieve maybe?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp not in front of my PC at the mo, will look at a demo when I get there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply Add New Label Image In JFrame
then
Set Jframe Background Transparents

```
frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
```