# find sub-images within an image

Tags: java, image, algorithm, image-processing, graphics

I want an efficient way to finding out sub-images from a Image for Ex. we have a image of country map and it contain states as sub-image.
Then i need a way to finding out sub-images of states from country map.

Comment: You might adapt the technique seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7059497/418556), using the 'border color' as the target color to identify.

Comment: *"we have a image of country map"*  How big is the image (in bytes)?  Can you upload it to ImageShack or another image sharing site?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only pixels, you'll need image processing algorithms to find sub-images.

Your solution will be specific to what the image you are processing looks like.  For example, if states are outlined in a certain color, you could try edge detection.  If states are each different colors, you could run a flood fill like algorithm to create boundaries for each state.

This is a difficult problem. Try `computer vision` or `object recognition` for keywords in your research.

However, I suggest instead you build up vector files which define boundaries of subimages by hand.  If you've only a few to do, this isn't a big deal.