# Java Collision Detection with custom images

Tags: java, swing, jframe, 2d

So I have a class. In this class I have a timer which repeats every 100 millisecs. I want to check If 2 objects collidate. Everthing is fine with rectangles and circles but custom images won't work or do only collide with one rectangle on the screen which is very weird.

```
private boolean checkCollision(GameObject ob1, GameObject ob2) {
     if(ob1.getBounds().intersects(ob2.getBounds())) return true;
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Use the code seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7059497/418556) to get shapes based on the image, then use the code seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14575043/418556) to determine when it collides with other shapes.

Comment: Found my mistake.. I'm so stupid I have a method to enable and disable collision for objects I disabled it for every object ....