# Get outline of Alphabet as Path in Android

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas, crop

I want to crop an image in alphabet(A-Z,0-9) in Andorid any idea ?

Here is an example of what I am looking for [Cut out image in shape of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295084/cut-out-image-in-shape-of-text) 
but he uses java's awt api(I am looking for Android) also it is too slow.

After some googling and reading android docs found that we can specified drawing area for canvas using  `canvas.clipPath(path)`  then I can draw a rectangular image on canvas and image will only be visible that is drawn in clipped area,hopefully :)

So now I can crop image in small rectangle and draw rectangle on Text path is it possible to get Outline of an Alphabet for given font ?

Answer (score 0):

On Android you should be able to do that very easily by using a [BitmapShader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapShader.html).

1. Instantiate your `BitmapShader`.
2. Instantiate a `Paint`, `and call setShader(bitmapShader)`.
3. Draw text with `Canvas.drawText("Cat", x,y, paint)`.