# Java Font Advance, Char Width

Tags: java, fonts, fontmetrics

### Context

The following code produces a "nice" looking `"Hello World"`

```
graphics.drawString("Hello World", 30, 30);
```

Now, if instead, I draw each character string, and manually advance by `fontMetrics.getCharWidth(c)` then I end up with a narrow/crowded looking `"Hello World"`.

### Questions

Why does this happen? What else do I need to add to, besides each character's "advance", to ensure that the characters are well spaced?

Comment: See also the `GlyphVector` as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6296381/418556).  Note that positions of letters might be affected by whether there is a white-space character before it and if not, what the preceding character is.  Why exactly are you trying to get the widths of individual characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which method in Graphics do you use to render char ?
here is the code that I wrote and it runs perfectly and results of both rendering methods are exactly the same,
would you please share that part of your code ?

```
public class Test1 extends JPanel{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test1 test = new Test1() ;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame() ;
    frame.add(test) ;
    frame.setSize(800 , 600) ;
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;
    frame.setVisible(true) ;

}


@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {     
    String text = "This is a text , Hello World!" ;

    g.drawString(text, 0, 100) ;        
    drawString(text, g, 0, 120) ;       
}

private void drawString (String s , Graphics g , int x , int y){
    for (int c1=0 ; c1 < s.length() ; c1++){

        char ch = s.charAt(c1); 
        g.drawString(ch+"", x, y) ;
        x+= g.getFontMetrics().charWidth(ch) ;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm an lazy idiot for not producing a minimal-working-example. As it turns out, the problem was that I was reading the FontMetrics for the _wrong_ font -- which is why my manual calculations failed.