# Draw string on ellipse

Tags: java, swing, awt, ellipse, drawstring

I'm happy with the output of my clock, however - I am not sure how to properly align my `drawString` for the numbers which should appear at the tip of each tick mark on the clock.
I am hoping someone might be able show the proper method/formula for this.

```
    private void drawTickMarks(Graphics2D g2)
    {
     double radius = this.faceRadius;

     for (int secs = 0; secs <= 60; secs++)
     {
         double tickStart;

         if (secs % 5 == 0)
             tickStart = radius - 15;
          else
             tickStart = radius - 5;

         tick = drawRadii(secs / 60.0, tickStart, radius);

         if (secs % 5 == 0)
            {
             g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));

                g2.drawString(""+(secs/5),(int)tick.getX1()+(int)(tick.getX1()-tick.getX2()),
                                                  (int)tick.getY1()+(int)(tick.getY1()-tick.getY2()));
            }
         else
             g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));


         g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
         g2.draw(tick);
     }
    }
```

Thanks to Thinhbk for a valid and correct solution with code and Jon W for the proper steps of coming to a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a supplemental to the solution provided by Jon W, I create a method that calculate the offset, and IMO, it looks fine. (@Jon W: sorry for not adding comment to your solution as it's rather long.)

```
 /**
     * Calculate the offset     * 
     * @param i
     * @return array: 
     * 0: x offset
     * 1: y offset
     */
    private int[] calculateOffSet(int i) {
        int[] val = new int[2];
        int deflt = -12;
        if(i == 12) {
            val[0] = -15;
            val[1] = 9;
        }else if (i > 6) {
            val[0] = deflt + i - 6 ;
            val[1] = i ;
        }else {
            val[0] = deflt + i ;
            val[1] = i + 6;         
        }
        return val;
    }
```

And in your code, just call this:

```
int xLocation = (int)tick.getX1()+(int)(tick.getX1()-tick.getX2());
int yLocation = (int)tick.getY1()+(int)(tick.getY1()-tick.getY2());
int[] offset = calculateOffSet((secs / 5));
g2.drawString(number, xLocation + offset[0], yLocation + offset[1]);
```

Comment: It does absolutely line up with your example as far as matching the tick, however the number is sort of covering the tick ...  Am I doing something wrong with the x,y location?  Am I doing this incorrectly?    g2.drawString(""+(secs/5), (int)tick.getX1() + offset[0], (int)tick.getY1() + offset[1]);

Answer (score 4):

If you imagine the String enclosed within a box, the x and y values you pass into `drawString` specify the lower left corner of the box.

I would modify the `drawString` line as such:

```
String number = ""+(secs/5);
int xLocation = (int)tick.getX1()+(int)(tick.getX1()-tick.getX2());
int yLocation = (int)tick.getY1()+(int)(tick.getY1()-tick.getY2());
int offsetX = /*Insert some value here to shift the position of all the strings
                along the x-axis. Make this an expression that contains number.length(),
                so that two-digit numbers are shifted more than one digit numbers. */
int offsetY = /*Insert some value here to shift the position of all the strings along
                the y-axis.*/
g2.drawString(number, xLocation + offsetX, yLocation + offsetY);
```

You'll have to play around with the specific values for `offsetX` and `offsetY` to make it look nice.

If you want to be even fancier and make it so that `drawString` will automatically adjust the location depending on what font is being used, take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html) and the `FontMetrics` class. You'll want to make `offsetX` and `offsetY` vary depending on width and height of the characters being drawn and whatnot.

Comment: +1 See also this [example of using a `GlyphVector`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6296381/418556) to get the size.