# String length in pixels in Java

Tags: java, string, fonts, awt, fontmetrics

Is there a way to calculate the length of a string in pixels, given a certain `java.awt.Font` object, that does not use any GUI components?

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295084/cut-out-image-in-shape-of-text/6296381#6296381) for using a `GlyphVector`.  It puts the final image in a GUI, but that is just to display it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> that does not use any GUI components?

It depends on what you mean here. I'm assuming you mean you want to do it without receiving a `HeadlessException`.

The best way is with a `BufferedImage`. AFAIK, this won't throw a `HeadlessException`:

```
Font font = ... ;
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
FontMetrics fm = img.getGraphics().getFontMetrics(font);
int width = fm.stringWidth("Your string");
```

Other than using something like this, I don't think you can. You need a graphics context in order to create a `FontMetrics` and give you font size information.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Graphics2D` object to get the font bounds (including the width):

```
Graphics2D g2d = ...
Font font = ...
Rectangle2D f = font.getStringBounds("hello world!", g2d.getFontRenderContext());
```

*But that depends on how you will get the `Graphics2D` object (for example from an `Image`).*

Comment: I assume that counts as a GUI component.

Comment: @GlenLamb I differ, `Image`'s are not GUI components.

Comment: I agree, but the specific need to do it WITHOUT GUI components would imply awt in general, otherwise the requirement makes little sense.

Comment: @GlenLamb  I don't understand what you are getting at.  The `Graphics2D` might be obtained from something like `img.getGraphics()` (or rather `img.createGraphics()`) in Brian's code.

Comment: @dacwe why would you specify "without GUI components" unless there was a need to avoid awt Graphics2d? Since that is pretty much how you would do it, even if you were using GUI.

Answer (score 2):

This gives the output of (137.0, 15.09375) for me. I have no idea what the units are, but it certainly looks proportionally correct and doesn't use Graphics2D directly.

```
    Font f = new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    Rectangle2D r = f.getStringBounds("Hello World! Hello World!", new FontRenderContext(null, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_DEFAULT, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_DEFAULT));
    System.out.println("(" + r.getWidth() + ", " + r.getHeight() + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get length and width of a string before paintComponent was called so I could size the enclosing panel to the text dimensions.  None of these techniques provided a sufficiently width and I did not have a Graphics object available.  I resolved the issue by setting my font to "Monospaced".