# How do I calculate the width of a string in pixels?

Tags: java, string, fonts, width

How to calculate width of a `String` in pixels in Java? *For e.g., I have a string say "Hello World!". What is its length in pixels, also considering its font family and size?*

Comment: Well, do you have a special font and font size in mind?

Comment: It can be arbitrarily anyone.

Comment: Edited your formatting to remove the code markup for length in particular.

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Drawing Mutliple Lines of Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/drawmulstring.html) and [`FontMetrics#stringWidth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html)

Comment: Are you asking anything different from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258486/calculate-the-display-width-of-a-string-in-java)?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345712/string-length-in-pixels-in-java) might also answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve what you want, based on what it is you want to achieve, for example...

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
System.out.println(fm.stringWidth("This is a simple test"));
g2d.dispose();
```

But this only has relevence for the `BufferedImage` and it's `Graphics` context, it will not translate back to say, something like a screen or printer.

However, so long as you have a `Graphics` context, you can achieve the same result.

This example, obviously, uses the default font installed for the `Graphics` context, which you can change if you need to...

Comment: I just have a `String`. I know its length, font family, font size. I want to calculate its size in pixels.

Comment: Fine, then you can use something like the above.  The width and height is depended on the `Graphics` context you are rendering to.  While you have the font family, font size and text, you are missing the key element

Answer (score 5):

In short: the question depends on the framework you are using. For example, if you are using AWT, and have a `Graphics` object `graphics`, and a `Font` object `font` you can do the following:

```
FontMetrics metrics = graphics.getFontMetrics(font);
int width = metrics.stringWidth("Hello world!");
```

Check out [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#stringWidth%28java.lang.String%29) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
Graphics2D g2d = ...
Font font = ...
Rectangle2D r = font.getStringBounds("hello world!", g2d.getFontRenderContext());
System.out.println("(" + r.getWidth() + ", " + r.getHeight() + ")");
```

Refer this [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html), may help you.

Comment: It seems a little convaluted considering you can use `Graphics#getFontMetrics`, but I'll give you an up vote for being different ;)

Answer (score 0):

there are couple of ways to do it, you can try `label.getElement().getClientWidth();` if the text is in a lable, if you're using AWT you can use `Graphics.getFontMetrics` then `FontMetrics.stringWidth`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FontMetrics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html). The FontMetrics class defines a font metrics object, which encapsulates information about the rendering of a particular font on a particular screen.

You can do something like below

```
    Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 10);  
    FontMetrics metrics = new FontMetrics(font) {  
    };  
    Rectangle2D bounds = metrics.getStringBounds("Hello World!", null);  
    int widthInPixels = (int) bounds.getWidth();
```

Comment: I've got a pretty good feeling that this isn't going to work.  The pixel size will be depended on the `Graphics` context, which you're passing `null` for...

Comment: Not sure how to cross verify the result but when I ran it I got 67 as the output for the string Hello World!.