# Rectangle fill using image

Tags: java, image, user-interface, awt, graphics2d

Using AWT, how do you import an image into a rectangle you have drawn? I want to assign the background to that particular rectangle only.

Comment: I recommend swing instead of awt. Then there is a good tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/overview/demo.html). regards

Answer (score 5):

1. Set the `Rectangle` as the clipping region.
2. Draw the image at a point so (part of) it is inside the clipping region.
3. Clear the clip.
4. Draw the rectangle.

As seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6296381/418556) (the shape here is of text, but same principle applies).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach is to override the the `paint` method in your component. Have a look at [Graphics.drawImage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29). Example: [Drawing an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html)

If you decide to move to `Swing`, you can take advantage of Swing's optimizied painting model, overriding `paintComponent` instead of `paint`.

See: [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)