# Java draw line with border

Tags: java, swing, awt, line, draw

I'm developing a JApplet in which the user can draw some lines over an image. 
Lines can be red or green, but I need to highlight them because I don't know the background color.

So I thought that I can draw a white "border" to the line, and I tried to do this creating other two white lines to the left and to the rigth of the original one. But the result is poor.

Is there a better way to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Can you share some of your code?

Comment: Yes, please post the code.

Comment: First draw a thick white line, then draw a thinner red or green line on top of the white line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Jesper, draw the line first using a thicker [`Stroke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html) (as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6296381/418556)).

[image]

The black outline on the letters has width 2.

```
g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
```