# Changing the colour of text in drawstring()

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d, styledtext

I'm trying to add emphasis to one work in a string im drawing using swing.

I was advised to use HTML with the following code:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g.drawString("this is something I want people to <p color="#00FF00">NOTICE</p>", x, y);
```

I tried this but had no luck... it just outputs the HTML

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need to escape your quotes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- How does this compile: `g.drawString("this is something I want people to <p color="#00FF00">NOTICE</p>", x, y);` as ' " ' is a special character we must escape it with *\*
- You cast to Graphics2D but dont use it (not relevant to problem but can cause anomalies).

It should be:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.drawString("this is something I want people to <p color=\"#00FF00\">NOTICE</p>", x, y);
```

to add colour simply call [`setColor(Color c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setColor%28java.awt.Color%29) on `Graphic`s object:

```
g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
```

However this will set the entire String to be drawn green, if you want only parts to be drawn green use [`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) for HTML support (up to HTML3.2):

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>this is something I want people to <p color=\"#00FF00\">NOTICE</p></html>");
```

full example:

[image]

**NB** As you can see notice is on its own line thats because of the *paragraph* tag rather use *font* tag to get it on a single line like so:

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>this is something I want people to <p color=\"#00FF00\">NOTICE</p></html>");

        // JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>this is something I want people to <font color=\"#00FF00\">NOTICE</font></html>");//will be shown on single line

        frame.add(label);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Good call on the escaped characters as well.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Graphics.setColor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setColor%28java.awt.Color%29) to change the color of anything you do. Or use a `JLabel` to set the color on.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `JLabel` for styled text.  See [LabelRenderTest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5853992/418556) for how it can be drawn to an image & used in paint.

[image]

### Using `Graphics`/AWT methods

The string implies `NOTICE` should be green, but the rest default (black). We would need to call `drawString(String)` twice with the colors of the two parts of the string, offsetting the latter string by the width of the first.  To get the width, see things like `FontMetrics` or a `GlyphVector`.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295084/cut-out-image-in-shape-of-text/6296381#6296381) uses a `GlyphVector` to get an outline of the letters.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this.. that looks a little over complicated to change the color of 1 word. Is this the only way to do this or are there any simpler options (I've only just started playing with swing)

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'm moving from println() to GUI and finding the transition a little difficult. When I was asing is there was a simpler option I was wondering if there was something less complex as I have no idea whats going on in that massive list of code you sent me. Your "hire someone" comment was not only nonconstructive but also quite off putting for someone struggling to learn a new skill.

Comment: See the edit.  I also recommend trying simpler things in GUIs.  Custom painting (especially of strings) is an advanced topic.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp  It **can** be done without using a styled text component (see the 'AWT edit') but it would be a lot of stuffing around.  I prefer to leverage the rendering ability of Swing to draw styled text.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just creating a simple label with emphasis on a word, you can just assign the HTML straight onto the `JLabel` like this...

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>this is something I want people to <p color='#00FF00'>NOTICE</p>");
```

As long as you have the `<html>` piece at the beginning of the String for a `JLabel`, it will use the HTML renderer to paint it.

As pointed out by @AndrewThompson, however, the `<p>` will force the colored text on to a new line, so perhaps `<span>` would be more appropriate...

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>this is something I want people to <span style='color:#00FF00;'>NOTICE</span>");
```

Comment: Excellent edit.  I only just noticed how odd that String is.  It reads like a single sentence, yet the HTML makes the last word into a new paragraph.

Comment: It certainly is interesting @AndrewThompson, something that a human can understand simply, can be interpreted very differently by a computer that relies on specific syntax.

Comment: @AndrewThompson see my upadted answer for why *NOTICE* is on its own line

Comment: I just upgraded 'good edit' to 'excellent edit'.  Using a `span` there makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

you can use g.setColor(Color.BLUE) before g.drawString(). (For example Color.BLUE)

Comment: The string implies `NOTICE` should be green, but the rest ..default.  We would need to call `drawString` **twice** with the two colors, offsetting the latter string by the width of the first.

Comment: you are right. As I know, you have only just solution for problem.

Comment: it inverts the color of original image and add text into black. is any other setup needs to be done to use this ?

Answer (score -2):

You could add g.setColor(Color.Chosen Color);and then write the string out with g.drawString()
perhaps

Comment: nothing new to at least one earlier answer, is there :-)