# Rounded Image in a java swing Jlabel

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, java-2d

I have been banging my head since morning on a a `Jlabel` issue; I would like to have an round image instead of the normal rectangular image for a label as shown in the image below.

[image]

I have tried overriding `paintComponent` in the label but the image would not display at all. I have not found a very concrete answer on previous SO posts. Your help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

My code is as below:

```
jLabelPic = new javax.swing.JLabel(){
BufferedImage image= null;
private Ellipse2D.Double border = new Ellipse2D.Double();
private int width=140, height=140;

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
 try {
image=     ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/image.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2d.setPaint(Color.RED);
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
border.setFrame(0, 0, width, height);
g2d.setClip(border);
g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, this);
}
};
```

Comment: can you share your code pls?

Comment: @ Soorapadman,I have posted the code above.

Comment: *"I have posted the code above."*  1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {`  Two tips: 1) Always call the `super` method first. 2) Never try to perform long running tasks (such as accessing the file system) in a paint method!  That stuff should be set up when the class is instantiated.

Comment: 1) See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6296381/418556) to 'Cut out image in shape of text'. 2) **`private Ellipse2D.Double border = new Ellipse2D.Double();`  Hmmm... using a 0 sized ellipse as a clip and not seeing anything.  And you think this problem is mysterious?**

Comment: @AndrewThompson: 1) Points taken, thanks. (2)The size if the ellipseis set in the line     border.setFrame(0, 0, width, height); Can you post a revision of my code with suggested modifications, please?

Comment: *"Can you post a revision of my code with suggested modifications.."*  What's your budget for *me* doing *your* work?!?  Either create and post an MCVE or don't.  It is up to **you.**  Voting to close (based on lack of MCVE).