# How to not to paint a certain part of background image?

Tags: java, image, swing, draw, java-2d

Code to paint a picture to a panel:

```
public class MyDraw extends JPanel {
  background = new ImageIcon("src/background.jpg").getImage();
@Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr){
 super.paintComponent(gr);
 gr.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 800, 600,   null);

}
}
```

I want to not to paint a the background picture in this circle, because I want to see the objects behind this circle.
**I don't want to put the object the front of the image, becuse the circle would move by pressing WASD.**

Like this:
[see image by clicking here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBrGF.jpg).

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6296381/418556) shows how to draw an image within a shape (of text). Use an `Ellipse2D` instead of the shape used in that example.

Comment: [What is the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)