# Render text contour in Java 2D

Tags: java, text, contour, graphics2d

How can I render contoured text like those in the images in Java? That is, the text has an outline with a background (which I already know how to do) and some texture around its outline.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this will give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295084/cut-out-image-in-shape-of-text/6296381#6296381. It shows how to create an outline of some text. You should be able to first `fill(...)` the Shape with a given color and then `draw(...)` the Shape with an outline color. You won't need the clipping logic.

Comment: Thank you twice: the direction of making the contour based on the outline itself and for putting me in contact with very interesting and promising stuff!